# SSL Authentication with Certificates: Should the Certificates have a hostname?

Tags: security, authentication, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

## Quick Version of Question

Gmail, TD (Canadian Bank), Royal Bank (Canadian Bank) all use ssl.  When you inspect their certificates they all have

```
Common Name (CN)   mail.google.com
```

Or more generally:

```
Common Name (CN)   <url>
```

Is this needed to prevent man in the middle attacks?

## Summary

JBoss allows clients and servers to authenticate using certificates and ssl.  One thing that seems strange is that you are not required to give your hostname on the certificate.

I think that this means if Server B is in your truststore, Sever B can pretend to be any server that they want.

(And likewise: if Client B is in your truststore...)

Am I missing something here?

## Authentication Steps

([Summary of Wikipeida Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake))

```
Client                                                  Server
=================================================================================================
1) Client sends Client Hello
        ENCRIPTION: None
        - highest TLS protocol supported
        - random number
        - list of cipher suites
        - compression methods

                                                        2) Sever Hello
                                                                ENCRIPTION: None
                                                                - highest TLS protocol supported
                                                                - random number
                                                                - choosen cipher suite
                                                                - choosen compression method

                                                        3) Certificate Message
                                                                ENCRIPTION: None
                                                                -

                                                        4) ServerHelloDone
                                                                ENCRIPTION: None

5) Certificate Message
        ENCRIPTION: None

6) ClientKeyExchange Message
        ENCRIPTION: server's public key => only server can read
                => if sever can read this he must own the certificate
        - may contain a PreMasterSecerate, public key or nothing (depends on cipher)

7) CertificateVerify Message
        ENCRIPTION: clients private key
        - purpose is to prove to the server that client owns the cert


                        8) BOTH CLIENT AND SERVER:
                                - use random numbers and PreMasterSecret to compute a common secerate


9) Finished message
        - contains a has and MAC over previous handshakes
                (to ensure that those unincripted messages did not get broken)


                                                        10) Finished message
                                                                - samething
```

## Sever Knows

- The client has the public key for the sent certificate (step 7)
- The client's certificate is valid because either:

  - it has been signed by a CA (verisign)
  - it has been self-signed BUT it is in the server's truststore
- It is not a replay attack because presumably the random number (step 1 or 2) is sent with each message

## Client Knows

- The server has the public key for the sent certificate (step 6 with step 8)
- The server's certificate is valid
      because either:

  - it has been signed by a CA (verisign)
  - it has been self-signed BUT it is in the client's truststore
- It is not a replay attack because presumably the random number (step 1 or 2)
      is sent with each message

## Potential Problem

- Suppose the client's truststore has certs in it:

  - Server A
  - Server B (malicous)
- Server A has hostname www.A.com
- Server B has hostname www.B.com
- Suppose: The client tries to connect to Server A but Server B launches a man in the middle attack.
- Since server B:

  - has a public key for the certificate that will be sent to the client
  - has a "valid certificate" (a cert in the truststore)
- And since:

  - certificates do not have a hostname feild in them

It seems like Server B can pretend to be Server A easily.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question.  Voting to move to Server Fault.

Comment: I think it is algorithm related...?

Comment: @david,  yes this is a programming question.  People on ServerFault do not fully understand secuirty because they are non-programmers.

Comment: @The Rook:  Okay, what is being programmed here?  (On a more personal note, based on our last exchange, I don't think you understand who understands security.  Your views seemed awfully black-and-white to me.)

Comment: @David Thornley Exploit writers are the only ones can fully understand secuirty.  And yes,  ether you can be compromised or you can't be compromised, that is a boolean.   The severity of the compromise is a float value.

Comment: @David Thornley  He is programming a client with a truststore to communicate with his jboss application and he wants to know if this approach is secure.

Comment: @The Rook:  Correction:  you can be compromised.  There is no "you can't be compromised" available, unless you render your system completely inaccessible (perhaps with thermite).  The questions are how easy it would be to compromise your system, and by what methods, and by whom, and what confidence level you have in the other answers.

Comment: @David Thornley I actually like what you just said.  Everything is vulnerable its comes down to how much effort you are willing to put into the attack.  There are new vulnerability types that are discovered which are used to compromise software that was thought to be very secure.  This happened with format strings in '99 and dangling pointers in 2005.

Comment: @The Rook - nah, it's not just exploit writers who understand security! Seriously, it's not.

Comment: @Michael I would like to be civil about this.  My point is that it doesn't take a whole lot time to write a successful exploit for a vulnerability that you find. If you haven't done this then it reflects on the effort that you put into your security research.

Answer (score 2):

Can you point to some text that says JBoss doesn't need a hostname in the cert, or is it simply your observation? I assume by 'hostname' you mean the Common Name (CN) or Distinguished Name (DN)??

*Normally* an application should check an X.509 cert for:

Valid date range
Usage (eg; server auth) 
Chains to a trusted root 
CN == DNS name of target host (it might be another name, not just DNS)
Not revoked (using a CRL or OCSP)

Technically, an app can choose to ignore any of these and simply indicate that all is well with the cert.... but that's bad :)

Comment: Hi Michael, I was following this tutorial: http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.3/doc/Server_Configuration_Guide/html/Using_JBoss_Login_Modules-BaseCertLoginModule.html .  It does not explicitly state that the hostname does not need to be in the generated certificate but it does not state otherwise either.  I have something that "authenticates and encrypts" right now  however I just realized that it does not have the hostname of the server.  Will this be a security hole?  Is there some way that I can force it to check the hostname.  Is this necessary?

Comment: Hey, if you're not checking the name of the 'other end' then you are subject to man-in-the-middle attacks. If you look at the docs you linked to, you'll see they have names in the certs, it's the CN= and OU= references.

Comment: The CN==DNS check is not strictly part of SSL/TLS. Instead, it's part of the policy of whether to trust a particular certificate for a site. In some cases, it's a perfectly reasonable thing to do (but you worry about whether some CA somewhere that you trust by default will get tricked into signing a false certificate for the server) and in others, not (especially when you only trust a single, restrictive CA; that's a viable approach for intranet apps where the clients aren't standard browsers).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing something, but I'm not sure if I understand your reasoning.

However, when server B tries to launch a man in the middle attack, you say that it has a public key. This is true, but to setup a ssl connection, you should also have a private key belonging to that public key. Moreover, the certificate used is coupled to the dns name (in case of https). So a client tries to connect to A, he types in www.a.com. Since we assume that B does not know the private key of A, he will have another keypair. He could never receive a valid (i.e. trusted) certificate from a major CA that is coupled to a domain he does not own.

So B could never get a certificate with common name www.A.com, for this reason, B could not perform a man in the middle attack.